# Sql query where table is connected to it self and create a array using php

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 1 table name `page_live`. Now I want to display it if `isMenu = 1`. Now it is connected to it self with filed name `parent_Id`.

As an example -
I have page_live named `test_page` and this row is a parent of a row named `inside-1`. And `inside-1` is parent of `inside-2`.

Now, I have to create array which will look like -

```
[0]=>{
 'name' => 'test_page'
 [0]=> {
  'name' => 'inside-1'
  [0] => {
    'name' => 'inside-2'
  }
 }
}
```

This is my table - 
[image]

Model `PageLive`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PageLive extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'page_live';

    protected $fillable = ['name', 'adminId', 'slugName', 'description',
'imageId', 'metaTitle', 'metaDesc', 'metaKeyword', 'pageTypeId', 'parent_id',
'isHome', 'pageDraftId', 'themeLayoutId'];

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(App\Http\Models\PageLive::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(App\Http\Models\PageLive::class, 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Please paste your relation codes and your model name

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your comment. Model name is ```PageLive```.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the relations in your PageLive model

Comment: Thank you. Updated.

Comment: your requested result array is not a valid array neither - can you please check it?

Comment: Yes checking it. Can you please help me to resolve this. This was just an example of array. But you can change format of array.

Comment: it would be good to have a clear example of PHP array that you are trying to output including multiple children example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212315/discussion-between-christophe-hubert-and-saurabh-gupte).

Answer (score 0):

You Need to use recursive relations in your Model:

```
public function childrenPages()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PageLive::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

public function allChildrenPages()
{
    return $this->childrenPages()->with('allChildrenPages');
}
```

Then in Controller:

```
$page = PageLive::with('allChildrenPages')->first();

$page->allChildrenPages; // collection of recursively loaded children
// each of them having the same collection of children:
$page->allChildrenPages->first()->allChildrenPages; // .. and so on
```

I can't guarantee it will be efficient for your data, I tried to give you the idea and part of the code, you need to test it definitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function to achieve this.

```
public function abc( $ar, $pid = null ) {
        $op = array();
        foreach( $ar as $item ) {
            if( $item['parent_id'] == $pid ) {
                $op[$item['id']] = $item;
                // using recursion
                $children =  $this->abc( $ar, $item['id'] );
                if( $children ) {
                    $op[$item['id']]['children'] = $children;
                }
            }
        }
        return $op;
    }
```

Use function something like this and call it wherever you want.

You will get array structure like -

```
array:1 [▼
  1 => array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "name" => "Test Page"
    "slugName" => "test-page"
    "parent_id" => null
    "children" => array:1 [▼
      3 => array:5 [▼
        "id" => 3
        "name" => "Inside 1"
        "slugName" => "test-page2"
        "parent_id" => "1"
        "children" => array:1 [▼
          4 => array:4 [▼
            "id" => 4
            "name" => "Inside 2"
            "slugName" => "test-page3"
            "parent_id" => "3"
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

Hope this will help you.